# Why is Promise returned in sequelize

Tags: javascript, object, promise, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am new to sequelize. So, I am writing a query where I map the parameters and find them in the db. But all I am getting is a Promise.
Here's my code

```
findData(params) {
   return params.map(product => {
      return Model.Stock.findAll({ raw: true })
        .then(stocks => stocks.map(stock => ({ success: true, data: stock })))
        .catch(err => ({ success: true, error: err.toString() }));
    });
  },
```

I am hoping to get objects, how do I do that?

```
0:Promise
_bitField:33554432
_fulfillmentHandler0:undefined
_promise0:undefined
_receiver0:undefined
_rejectionHandler0:Array(4)
_trace:CapturedTrace
__proto__:Object
length:1
__proto__:Array(0)
```

What should I change in order to return objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation For ( Why its returning promise ) :**

```
findData(params) {
   return params.map(product => { // <-------- 2. So this will return array of promise objects
      return Model.Stock.findAll({ raw: true }) //<------- 1. This will always returning promise , nature of sequlize
        .then(stocks => stocks.map(stock => ({ success: true, data: stock })))
        .catch(err => ({ success: true, error: err.toString() }));
    });
},
```

**Solution 1 :**

```
Promise.all(findData(params)) // <-------- 3. Use Promise.all to solve all promise and get data from all   
.then(stocs => {
    console.log(stocks); //<----------- 4. console log your out put and you will get idea
});
```

---

**Solution 2 :**

```
findData(params) {
   return Promise.all(params.map(product => { 
      return Model.Stock.findAll({ raw: true })
        .then(stocks => stocks.map(stock => ({ success: true, data: stock })))
        .catch(err => ({ success: true, error: err.toString() }));
    }));
},
```

**then you can get data like :**

```
findData(params).then(your_data => { ..... })
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to read a bit about promises, and how to effectively use them. You can find many examples around.

In your particular case, looking at the code, you do receive an object.
Take a look at:

```
.then(stocks => stocks.map(stock => ({ success: true, data: stock })))
```

Lets break it even more:

```
stocks => stocks.map
```

Stocks should (concluding by the name) have an array of objects.

In your case, you could use it as follows:

```
findData(params).then(function(yourObjects) {

    //do something here...
});
```